# SoftmaxLayer Incompatible types

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, segmentation

Trying to create U-Net similar to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) from this [GitHub project](https://github.com/orobix/retina-unet) but keep getting "incompatible type" error on the final softmax layer. Any ideas for how to organize data to satisfy Softmax layer?  Or is this a bug?  Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
conv[numFilters_Integer] := NetChain[
 {
  ConvolutionLayer[numFilters, {3, 3}, "Stride" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 1],
  ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
  ConvolutionLayer[numFilters, {3, 3}, "Stride" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 1],
  ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]
 }
]

net = NetGraph[
 {
  conv[32],
  PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 0],
  conv[64],
  PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 0],
  conv[128],
  NeuralNetworks`UpsampleLayer[2],
  CatenateLayer[],
  conv[64],
  NeuralNetworks`UpsampleLayer[2],
  CatenateLayer[],
  conv[32],
  ConvolutionLayer[2, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 1, "PaddingSize" -> 0],
  ReshapeLayer[{32*32, 2}],
  SoftmaxLayer[]
  },
 {
  1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6,
  6 -> 7, 3 -> 7,
  7 -> 8, 8 -> 9,
  9 -> 10, 1 -> 10,
  10 -> 11, 11 -> 12, 12 -> 13, 13 -> 14
 },
 "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You can't feed matrix to `SoftmaxLayer`, it requires a vector.

Comment: Try inserting `FlattenLayer` in between.

Answer (score 6):

Very happy to report that MMA 11.1 has solved this issue with

```
NetMapOperator[]
```

which is used together with the `SoftmaxLayer[]` as the operator to perform the pixel per pixel classification (i.e. segmentation)

Also, new in 11.1 is the `ResizeLayer[]` which replaces `UpsampleLayer[]`

So the final network definition is:

```
net = NetGraph[
    {
        conv[32],
        PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Stride" -> 2],
        conv[64],
        PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Stride" -> 2],
        conv[128],
        ResizeLayer[{Scaled[2], Scaled[2]}],
        CatenateLayer[],
        conv[64],
        ResizeLayer[{Scaled[2], Scaled[2]}],
        CatenateLayer[],
        conv[32],
        ConvolutionLayer[2, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 1],
        ReshapeLayer[{32*32, 2}],
        NetMapOperator[SoftmaxLayer[]],
        ReshapeLayer[{32, 32, 2}]
    }, 
    {
        1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 
        3 -> 7, 
        7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 
        1 -> 10, 
        10 -> 11, 11 -> 12, 12 -> 13, 13 -> 14, 14 -> 15
    },
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

According to documentation, `softmax` activation in Keras works fine with one more dimenstion (nb_timesteps), it would ignore it anyway.

**softmax: Softmax applied across inputs last dimension. Expects shape either (nb_samples, nb_timesteps, nb_dims) or  (nb_samples, nb_dims)**

Here you need to change the last part a bit:

```
FlattenLayer[], SoftmaxLayer[], ReshapeLayer[{32 32, 2}]
```

Comment: Not sure flatten is the right answer here since we want to classify each input pixel as blood vessel or not blood vessel.  If use flatten then softmax is taken over all pixels.  Want the softmax per pixel (i.e. segmentation).  I'm happy to give it a try though.  Thanks

Comment: @AbelBrown, There is a NeuralNetworks`SplitLayer, maybe it is useful, but I can't figure out how to use it yet.